# How to send order confirmation email in Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: commerce

I want to send an automatic email when a customer makes a purchase ie thank you for your purchase of x, y, x (and I have seen this described as "[outrageously complex](https://www.drupal.org/node/1471758#comment-9169347)"!).

Commerce Kickstart 2 has a rule called "commerce_order_message_order_notification" where the action is "send message with message notify". (Screenshot 1 below)

Where does the rule define which message this action refers to ie does it already refer to the message "commerce order: order confirmation" (Screenshot 2 below) or do I need to configure this?

Also do I need to configure the data selector in the rule reaction (Screenshot 3 below)

In other words I think there is no order email confirmation out of the box with CK2 so what configuration do I need to do?

Thanks...

Screenshot 1

[image]

Screenshot 2

[image]

Screenshot 3

[image]

Comment: Please re-take your screenshots at or under 630px of page width. That's the maximum width of images Drupal Answers will show without scaling.

Comment: I think You should define a rule by your self.

Event:after completing the checkout.

check :order is a commerce order or not.

action :Send Email and By using mimesystem module you can send html mails . now you need order number email id amount and billing address. these you can get it from tokens or you can use php code to get these values